# On-ear wireless (non-Bluetooth) headphones with duplex high-quality audio?

Tags: wireless, headphones

I'm looking for wireless headphones with the following properties:

- **Most importantly:** Can capture audio via the microphone at the same time as playing **high-quality stereo** audio out the headphones.
- **Very important:** Imperceptibly low latency. The two wireless protocols I've seen on the market that accomplish this so far, are AptX Low Latency (with Bluetooth A2DP), and SteelSeries' proprietary protocol with the Siberia 840. I will still buy headphones from another vendor if they can get the latency down similar to these protocols (around 5 to 15 milliseconds is good).
- **Important:** Noise cancelling headphones and mic.
- **Important:** On-ear or slight over-ear. The shape of the pads I'm looking for is below.
- **Important:** The "base station" or "transmitter" should interface with the computer using USB and expose a "sound card" device.
- **Important:** *Shouldn't be Bluetooth*. To the best of my knowledge, Bluetooth audio devices do not, at all, support the duplex audio with stereo audio out at the same time as the mic in. If this is wrong, show me a counterexample! And no, HFP profile doesn't count, because the quality of the playback audio in the headphones is *horrifically bad* -- about 8 kHz and mono channel with horrible lossy compression.
- **Important:** At least 10m range.
- **Nice to have:** At least 10 hours of battery life. 8 is okay.
- **Nice to have:** Swappable batteries.
- **Not required at all:** Support to work with smartphones. This is for high-end audio listening and gaming with a desktop or laptop PC.

Basically I'm looking for something like the [Steelseries Siberia 840](https://steelseries.com/gaming-headsets/siberia-840) but with ear cups of a shape/size similar to the [BeoPlay H8](https://www.beoplay.com/products/beoplayh8).

**This** is the ideal ear cup shape/size for me, having worn them extensively over the course of a year:

[image]

[image]

If it weren't for the lack of the

> - **Most importantly:** Can capture audio via the microphone at the same time as playing **high-quality stereo** audio out the headphones.

feature, the BeoPlay H8 would be my **Perfect Headset**.

How close can I get to the H8's quality/shape/design/size while getting the Most Important feature?